# ReSharper Reformat, array initialization, space after comma

Tags: c#, formatting, resharper

ReSharper reformats code

```
int[] array = new int[width, height];
```

to

```
int[] array = new int[width,height];
```

But I want a space after comma! Can't find this setting in options...

Answer (score 0):

If you go to Resharper options->Languagues->C#->Formatting Style->Spaces, there is an option under "Other" called "After comma"

If you activate that, Resharper will add the space you are looking for.
Beware that it also changes that in method calls and probably in other places too.